# Selecting data from the list based on specific part of the string

Tags: python, web-scraping

Highly appreciate your efforts to help me! 
I am trying some small scraping project of mine. I have got a list of links from webpage, and now I want to select only links that are related to products from navigation.

I was wondering is there a way to select all links from array that have "product" in their name. For example i want all the links from website navigation that have word "blog" in them.

Appreciate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [Beautiful Soup library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). You could do the following assuming that the site you want to scrape is stored as `html`:

```
b = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
links = [i['href'] for i in b.find_all('a') if "blog" in i['href']]
```

This makes a list of the `href` tags of each link on the page and then filters that list for elements that contain the string `blog`.